# what's the differences between Supplier<X> and Supplier<? extends X>

Tags: java, wildcard, option-type, supplier

In "Optional" source code, I found this function:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

My question is if I change the function to this, it looks like working same

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: Well, there is a difference. Your suggestion wont be able to take a `Supplier<ChildException>` that throws a `ChildException` while having `throws ParentException` in its signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this method:

```
void example() throws IOException {
  throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

This declares that it throws the general `IOException`, but concretely throws a more specific exception, `FileNotFoundException`.

Same with `orElseThrow`: by accepting an upper-bounded supplier, it can throw a more specific exception type.

The difference is irrelevant in most cases, because you can always catch/`throws` a more general exception type. A case where I can think it may make a difference is when you are accepting the `Supplier` as a parameter:

```
<X extends IOException> void example(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
    throws IOException {  // Note IOException, not X.
  Optional.empty().orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier);
}
```

You can invoke this with either of the following suppliers as the argument:

```
Supplier<IOException> s1 = IOException::new;
Supplier<FileNotFoundIOException> s2 = FileNotFoundIOException::new;
```

but you couldn't do the latter without the upper bound on `Supplier<? extends X>`.